# Question on translation complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $ given by f($\mathbb{Z}$)=$\mathbb{Z}+b$, b is a complex number say $(b_1,b_2)$. How do i deduce what is the picture of range of f where domain is restricted by set of complex numbers such that $|Z|=1$.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$Z$ is the circle with radius $1$ centered at the origin. Adding $b$ gives you the circle with radius $1$ centered at $b$.

Comment: How to prove this?

Comment: If $y \in f(Z)$ then $y = z + b$ where $z \in Z$. Thus $y-b \in Z$ so that $|y-b| = 1$.

Comment: any simple method please

Comment: Addition by a complex number is a translation. I'm not sure what "simple method" you are seeking.